# Make error: missing separator

Tags: makefile

I am getting the following error running `make`:

```
Makefile:168: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makefile:4: \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)

Comment: There are lots of comments about "bad error message".  But, this message `missing separator` is just make's version of a generic _syntax error_, or "I have no idea what the heck you are trying to do here".  It's not really feasible to provide a better error because make can't figure out what this line is supposed to be.  Make's parser works with "separators": if it finds a `=` then it's a variable assignment, if it finds a `:` then it's a rule, if it starts with a TAB (or `.RECIPEPREFIX` character) it's a recipe.  If none of those things then... it has no idea.

Answer (score 543, accepted):

As indicated in the [online manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html), the most common cause for that error is that lines are indented with spaces  when `make` expects tab characters.

### Correct

```
target: 
\tcmd
```

where `\t` is TAB (`U+0009`)

### Wrong

```
target:
....cmd
```

where each `.` represents a SPACE (`U+0020`).

Comment: You can use .RECIPEPREFIX to change the character make uses. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#Special-Variables

Comment: To confirm, I just ran into this myself. Most editors/IDEs can help spot this. For example, in IDEA, go to the View menu, choose "Active Editor", "Show Whitespaces". I can't believe that spaces vs. tabs is still a thing in (checks notes) 2022.

Comment: I had a string variable that contained newlines - not by choice. Snuck in via `execute_process`, fixed with `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` seeing as the output is single-line. Infuriatingly bad error message though

Answer (score 23):

Just for grins, and in case somebody else runs into a similar error:

I got the infamous "missing separator" error because I had invoked a rule defining a function as

```
($eval $(call function,args))
```

rather than

```
$(eval $(call function,args))
```

i.e. **`($`** rather than **`$(`**.

Comment: What? :) I guess you didn't have `0x20` "space" there, is that correct?

Comment: @user35443 The placement of `$`

Answer (score 8):

This is a syntax error in your Makefile. It's quite hard to be more specific than that, without seeing the file itself, or relevant portion(s) thereof.

Answer (score 7):

For me, the problem was that I had some end-of-line `# ...` comments embedded within a `define ... endef` multi-line variable definition.  Removing the comments made the problem go away.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know comments in `define` directive are treated literally. Actually the behavior is **not** explain in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multi_002dLine). (For clarity: Embedding a number sign `#` within the directive isn't itself a syntax error. But it is just not interpreted as a start of a comment, so doing that is admittedly error-prone.)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this error was caused by the lack of a mere space. I had this if block in my makefile:

```
if($(METHOD),opt)
CFLAGS=
endif
```

which should have been:

```
if ($(METHOD),opt)
CFLAGS=
endif
```

with a space after if.

Comment: just why, why...

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was actually **missing** a tab in between `ifeq` and the command on the next line.  No spaces were there to begin with.

```
ifeq ($(wildcard $DIR_FILE), )
cd $FOLDER; cp -f $DIR_FILE.tpl $DIR_FILE.xs;
endif
```

Should have been:

```
ifeq ($(wildcard $DIR_FILE), )
<tab>cd $FOLDER; cp -f $DIR_FILE.tpl $DIR_FILE.xs;
endif
```

Note the **`<tab>`** is an actual tab character

Answer (score 5):

My error was on a variable declaration line with a multi-line extension. I have a trailing space after the "\" which made that an invalid line continuation.

```
MY_VAR = \
   val1 \ <-- 0x20 there caused the error.
   val2
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case error caused next. I've tried to execute commands globally i.e outside of any target.

UPD. To run command globally one must be properly formed. For example command

```
ln -sf ../../user/curl/$SRC_NAME ./$SRC_NAME
```

would become:

```
$(shell ln -sf ../../user/curl/$(SRC_NAME) ./$(SRC_NAME))
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the same error was caused because colon`:` was missing at end as in `staging.deploy:`. So note that it can be easy syntax mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I had the missing separator file in Makefiles generated by qmake. I was porting Qt code to a different platform. I didn't have QMAKESPEC nor MAKE set.  Here's the link I found the answer:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/3783/missing-separator-error-in-makefile/5

Answer (score 1):

Just to add yet another reason this can show up:

```
$(eval VALUE)
```

is not valid and will produce a "missing separator" error.

```
$(eval IDENTIFIER=VALUE)
```

is acceptable. This sort of error showed up for me when I had an macro defined with `define` and tried to do

```
define SOME_MACRO
... some expression ...
endef

VAR=$(eval $(call SOME_MACRO,arg))
```

where the macro did not evaluate to an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I had this because I had no colon after `PHONY`

Not this,

```
.PHONY install
install:
    install -m0755 bin/ytdl-clean /usr/local/bin
```

But this (notice the colon)

```
.PHONY: install
...
```

Answer (score -3):

Following Makefile code worked:

```
obj-m = hello.o

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules 

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Please  elaborate

Answer (score -3):

So apparently, all I needed was the "build-essential" package, then to run `autoconf` first, which made the `Makefile.pre.in`, then the `./configure` then the `make` which works perfectly...

Comment: completely not understandable answer, not applicable to the question in any way