# Make Error: Missing Separator

Tags: makefile, rexec

I am attempting to install rexec into Redhat Enterprise Release 4.  Everytime I attempt to use the make command I get the following error.

Makefile:15: *** missing separator.   Stop.

I have looked elsewhere on the net and line 15 of the Makefile has the below:

.include    (I am unsure why but this website is blanking out what comes after .include, it is bsd.kmod.mk surrounded by <>)

I have used vi to make sure that space in the middle is a TAB and not 8 spaces, this does not resolve the issue.  I have placed a TAB in front of the .include as I read somewhere there has to be a tab at the beginning, I then get a different error:

make: *** No rule to make target 'rexec.ko' , needed by 'load'.   Stop.

I am unsure what else I'm supposed to do to get rexec installed, any clues?

Entire Makefile:

SRCS    = rexec.c vnode_if.h
KMOD    = rexec
KO  = ${KMOD}.ko
KLDMOD  = t

KLDLOAD     = /sbin/kldload
KLDUNLOAD   = /sbin/kldunload

load: ${KO}
    ${KLDLOAD} -v ./${KO}

unload: ${KO}
    ${KLDUNLOAD} -v -n ${KO}

.include  (I am unsure why but this website is blanking out what comes after .include, it is bsd.kmod.mk surrounded by <>)

Comment: What "make" are you using i.e what is the output of "make --version"?

Comment: BTW, generally you need to escape an opening angle bracket by writing &lt; instead of that character. Similarly an ampersand(&) would need to be escaped as &amp;.

Comment: Output of make --version is GNU Make 3.80

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make error: missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the .include should be using spaces.  Check out the last part of the Makefile.  It should end like this:

```
unload: ${KO}
<tab>${KLDUNLOAD} -v -n ${KO}

.include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

Where <tab> is an actual tab character.  And that blank line better be blank; no tricksy whitespace on it.

Comment: when I VI the file the space before "${KLDUNLOAD} -v -n ${KO}" is a tab, am I supposed to type a character into it?  I'd be confused if that was the issue as it keeps complaining about line 15 where the .include is.  And there is a blank line from what I can tell, again using VI.

Comment: No character to add, just wanted to check it was a tab.  The problem is just figuring out a way to show white space which is why making white space matter is so evil.  I was just guessing based on the possibility that an earlier error broke the .include.  But I think @Maxi has it right with the BSD vs. GNU situation.