# Error message from make: missing separator

Tags: makefile, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make error: missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)

I've made many makefiles, but today I was making an easy one and it doesn't work because it is missing a separator.

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall
LDFLAGS =
MODULOS = externa libreria ann
PARTES = metodos backprop BackApp
EXECUTABLE = atras

.PHONY: clean install uninstall

all: externa libreria ann
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) –c $(PARTES).o –o $(EXECUTABLE)

external: metodos.cpp metodos.h
    $(CC) –c $(CFLAGS) metodos.cpp 

libreria: backprop.cpp backprop.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) –c backprop.cpp

ann: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) –c BackApp.cpp

clean:
    rm –f $(PARTES).o

install:
    cp juego /usr/games/juego

uninstall:    
    sudo rm /usr/games/juego
```

The error concerns the next line after external, line 14. The error says:

```
*** missing separator
```

but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably have spaces instead of tabs for indentation on that line.

Comment: thanks, that's solve. What a stupid error.