# Makefile:4: *** missing separator

Tags: makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make error: missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)

I am so stressed out by this silly error...

This is the [file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0GDyEdUryzERkY1VncwdkpmQXc)...

I've spent an hour trying to find out what's wrong with it.... I am a VIM user.
Can someone point out why? I use tab!

Thanks.

```
all: hello

hello:  hello_world.c   
    gcc -Wall -o hello.exe hello_world.c
```

Comment: Can you inline that Makefile in your question (and mark it up)?

Comment: @Flexo I am not sure if that's a good idea. I've copied and pasted many from stackoverflow and they seen to be bad when i do it. I even set `set paste` in vim. But I will do it in just a moment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The line that has the gcc command should start with a tab, and it seems you are using expanded tabs (spaces instead of tabs). Try using `set noexpandtab` in `vim`.

Comment: Thanks. It solved. That was the real problem... bad configuration.

Comment: @User007 Glad to be of help! Happened to me so many times ... :D

Answer (score 3):

This is what you have:

```
all: hello

hello:  hello_world.c   
    gcc -Wall -o hello.exe hello_world.c
```

The whitespace before the `gcc` command HAS to be a <kbd>Tab</kbd> , not one space, not two spaces, not 3 spaces and so on, but one, and exactly one tab

Comment: I believe I have one tab, but I think marcelog is right about my vim setting. But thanks for pointing out, nos. GOod reminder.

Comment: @User007 The file you linked to in your question contains 4 spaces before the gcc command. Make sure your vim settings does not convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: Yes. Because my configuration made me think it was tab :) Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 1):

No you don't!

I have downloaded your file -- there four space in it, not tab.
You can run `:set list` in vim to see it yourself.

Please remove the spaces and put the tab instead of it (press ctrl-v ctrl-i).

In future you can add

```
 # vim:noet
```

to the file. And your default setting will be overridden by `set noexpandtab` setting of the file.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it has to do with my vim setting! (:

Comment: @User007: That's right! run `:set noexpandtab` and try to insert Tab once again.