# c++ makefile missing separator issue

Tags: c++, makefile

i'm not sure why my makefiles isn't working. i googled the the error and i got some stuff about whitespaces and tabs but i'm not sure what to do.

error: makefile:17: *** missing separator.  Stop.

```
# see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html
#     http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-c -Wall -g
LDFLAGS=
OBJECTS= main.o Player.o Territory.o Continent.o Game.o Color.o
TITLE=ass1
ARCHIVE=$(TITLE).tar.gz

.PHONY : all clean debug valgrind archive

# make all
all: $(OBJECTS) $(TITLE)

# make ass
$(TITLE): $(OBJECTS)
$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

# make %.o
%.o: %.cpp %.h
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^

# make clean
clean :
rm -f *.o *.gch $(TITLE) 

# make debug
debug : $(TITLE)
cgdb ./$<

# make valgrind P0=-Test P1=0
valgrind : $(TITLE)
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./$< $(P0) $(P1)

# http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar
archive :
tar cfz $(ARCHIVE) --ignore-failed-read *.cpp *.h *.pdf Makefile

# additional dependencies

main.o: Continent.h Player.h Territory.h 
Player.o: Player.h
Territory.o: Territory.h
Continent.o: Continent.h
Game.o: Game.h
Color.o: Color.h
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make error: missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command need to be tab (not space) indented. For example,

```
$(TITLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
^ this is a tab (in disguise...)
```

Comment: Ah... the memories of trying to figure this one out the hard way (long before SO existed).

Comment: With [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) it just needs to be indented more than the first line.  No need to worry about these archaic tab problems.