# error "missing separator" in build qwt-6.1

Tags: makefile, qmake, qwt

My environment:

```
QT: Qt_5_0_2
QWT: qwt-6.1-rc3
MinGW: mingw47_32
OS: win7_32
```

I follow the introduction file "INSTALL"'s step:

```
C) Win32/MinGW 
Check that your Qt version has been built with MinGW - not with MSVC !

Start a Shell, where Qt4 is initialized. ( F.e. with
"Programs->Qt by Trolltech ...->Qt 4.x.x Command Prompt" ).
Check if you can execute "make" or something like "mingw32-make".

qmake qwt.pro
make
make install
```

I get the error in the step "make":

```
C:\qwt-6.1-rc3>qmake qwt.pro

C:\qwt-6.1-rc3>mingw32-make
cd src\ && ( if not exist Makefile E:\Qt\5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin\qmake.exe C:
\qwt-6.1-rc3\src\src.pro -o Makefile ) && mingw32-make -f Makefile
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/qwt-6.1-rc3/src'
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/qwt-6.1-rc3/src'
Makefile.Release:305: *** missing separator.  Stop.
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/qwt-6.1-rc3/src'
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release-all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/qwt-6.1-rc3/src'
makefile:44: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first-ordered' failed
mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

The lines **304,305** in "Makefile.Release" are:

```
304 qmake:  FORCE
305     @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile.Release src.pro
```

Where is wrong?

thanks

Comment: [This is probably a formatting error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator). Does it happens if you delete the makefile and start back at step 1?

Comment: I found I can build the QWT in QTCreator successed. But I do not know how to intergate QWT to QTCreator. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess your broken Makefile is leftover from some earlier attempts - remove the Qwt build directory completely and start from scratch.

For loading the Qwt designer plugin in the Qt creator you need to have a version that is compatible with how the creator had been built. AFAIR the 5.0.2 mingw package contains a version 2.7.0 of the creator, that had been built for Qt 4.8 with MSVC ( see About->Qt creator ). If true it means you need to have 2 different builds of Qwt - one for your application, the other one for the designer plugin.

For the future I'm planning to offer precompiled versions of the designer plugin that are compatible with current binary packages of the Qt creator.

Also note that in SVN trunk the default settings for building the plugin have been changed since rc3: on windows the library is statically linked into the plugin and on better systems you have a similar effect with compiling in the install path of the library ( see RPATH ).

Comment: I found an other way http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-36498.html to build qwt:
1.qmake.exe qwt.pro -spec win32-g++ -r CONFIG+=release
2.mingw32-make release
3.mingw32-make install

Comment: Another question: how to tell my Qt creator is been built for MSVC?
The information in About->Qt creator is
"
Qt Creator 2.7.0 
Based on Qt 5.0.2 (32 bit)

Built on Apr 9 2013 at 09:32:03

From revision b6257ef735

Copyright 2008-2013 Digia Plc. All rights reserved.

The program is provided AS IS with NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, INCLUDING THE WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
"

Answer (score 3):

```
Makefile.Release:305: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

This usually means this `Makefile` is not of the right format for `mingw32-make`;

Since the `Makefile` is generated by `qmake`, you should check the `QMAKESPEC` of your `qmake`. It should be `win32-g++`, not `win32-mvsc`.

This issue is strongly linked to the first warning of the `qwt` *INSTALL* note :

> Check that your Qt version has been built with MinGW - not with MSVC !

Comment: My Qt is install from "qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-mingw47_32-x86-offline.exe".

And i run the "make" in "Qt 5.0.2 for Desktop (MinGW 4.7)" command line.

Is this mean my Qt was been build with MSVC?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was that I wanted to prepare sources second time. I had sources in svn floder. I solved proble erasing folder and update sources again. After this operation I was able to run 'qmake proj.pro' correctly.