# GNUmakefile handles echo in ifeq

Tags: gnu-make

Say I have the following in the GNUmakefile

```
ifeq ($(MODELS), abc)
  @echo PASS  <== line 45
endif
```

How come I keep on getting the following error?

GNUmakefile:45: * missing separator. Stop.

Pls note, the echo works fine if it is NOT in the ifeq clause

Comment: Is that inside of a target body? Because it isn't legal outside of one. If it is inside a target body then you likely just need to indent it with a tab instead of spaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make error: missing separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)

Answer (score 0):

ah I know why. You need to make sure there is NO space/TAB before "ifeq", "endif" and NO space before the $echo.For the echo line, it can only be TABs. Why do GNUmakefile is so picky on spaces/tabs, these invisible rules are really not institutive.