# C: Creating static library and linking using a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries

I am trying to [understand static and shared Libraries](http://randu.org/tutorials/c/libraries.php).

I want to do the following to create a makefile that does separate compilation and linking such that a static library is created and linked
in forming the final static executable.

I have the following code for the Makefile, but I am getting the following error

`Makefile:13: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

But I am also trying to understand how to actually link/create libraries.

If I run the commands after `line 12` in the terminal they work, but not in the makefile.

```
myProgram: main.o addSorted.o freeLinks.o
    gcc -lm -o myProgram main.o addSorted.o freeLinks.o

main.o: main.c
    gcc -O -c -lm main.c main.h

addSorted.o: addSorted.c addSorted.h
    gcc -O -c -lm addSorted.c

freeLinks.o: freeLinks.c freeLinks.h
    gcc -O -c -lm freeLinks.c

ar rc libmylib.a main.o addSorted.o freeLinks.o    //Error Line

ranlib libmylib.a

gcc -o foo -L. -lmylib foo.o

clean:
    rm -f myProgram main.o addSorted.o freeLinks.o
```

Also, if you can assist in improving the code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make error: missing separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)

Comment: The three `ar`, `ranlib` and `gcc` lines are supposed to be the recipe for what target?

Comment: @EtanReisner I am new to C/makefile and libraries. I guess for `myProgram`. That's why I need assistance. Also the line where I am getting error, does not contain `tab`

Comment: Q: "the line where I am getting error, does not contain tab..."  A: That's the problem.  You need a "target" (e.g. `mylib.a`, left justified), followed by two lines that begin with a "tab" (`ar rc libmylib.a main.o addSorted.o freeLinks.o`, then `ranlib libmylib.a`).  The two lines must be consecutive (no intervening blank lines).  Here is a good tutorial: [A Simple Makefile Tutorial](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)

Comment: the gcc linker handles the command line parameters in the order that they are listed.  the linker will not include anything from a library unless there is an unresolved name the needs satisfying.  therefore, nothing will be linked from the math library.  Suggest moving the '-lm' to the end of the linker command line.

Comment: the gcc compiler has absolutely no need for external libraries.,  so the compile statements should not have '-lm'

Comment: the format of a makefile rule is: 1) destinationFile : sourceFile all other dependencies   2) each  command line following the first line must be indented, with a tab.   The lines your having a problem with are not formatted correctly

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
all: myProgram

myProgram: main.o libmylib.a #libmylib.a is the dependency for the executable
        gcc -lm -o myProgram main.o -L. -lmylib

main.o: main.c
        gcc -O -c main.c main.h

addSorted.o: addSorted.c addSorted.h
        gcc -O -c addSorted.c

freeLinks.o: freeLinks.c freeLinks.h
        gcc -O -c freeLinks.c

libmylib.a: addSorted.o freeLinks.o #let's link library files into a static library
        ar rcs libmylib.a addSorted.o freeLinks.o

libs: libmylib.a

clean:
        rm -f myProgram *.o *.a *.gch #This way is cleaner than your clean
```

This set of rules first compiles all files, then it makes library (libmylib.a) target and uses it's artifact to link the executable.
I also added separate redundant target form making libs only.
Needed files:

```
user@host> ls
addSorted.c  addSorted.h  freeLinks.c  freeLinks.h  main.c  main.h Makefile
```

Comment: So libraries are only made from all the files, except `main`?. And once I have created the library, it is linked to `myProgram`? This helps.

Comment: Would `Shared Libraries` also would work similarly? Or I have to invoke the same from `main`

Comment: @user3337714 Yes, that is. You also may construct a separate library for each non-main file or link one bunch of files into one library and another group of files into another. Just make libraries in the way you want, joining files by their purpose to sustain clarity of your project structure.

Comment: @Dmitri Surely, forgot to remove that. Corrected the answer.

Comment: @user3337714 Shared libraries should be build simultaneously from the point of view of Makefile. Just compile `*.o` files with `-fpic` and links with `-shared`. Here is a good explanation (not about makefiles, shared libs only): http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

Comment: `main.o: main.c
        gcc -O -fpic -lm main.c main.h`. Would this be correct way of doing for Shared?

Comment: @user3337714 No. I meant `gcc -c -fpic freeLinks.c` and `gcc -c -fpic addSorted.c`. Then `gcc -shared -o libmylib.so freeLinks.o addSorted.o` to craft a shared library. Then you can link an executable with it using `-lmylib`, and don't forget to add it's directory to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` of the shell where you're going to run the executable.

Comment: @user3337714 You also do NOT need linkning flags (i.e. `-lm`) on compilation steps. I corrected the proposed makefile in the answer.

Comment: @user3337714 Obviously, you can not have different files with the same name (`*.o` files with `-fpic` and without it), so to make shared and static libs simultaneously you should use subdirectories or different file naming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83280/discussion-between-user3337714-and-sergey).

Comment: 'all' 'libs' 'clean' need to be listed as dependences in a 'PHONY : all libs clean' rule.    Always place the 'all' target as the first target in the file, so when no specific target is specified, that is the target that is performed first by the make utility

Comment: when calling 'ar',  it would be better to include the 's' modifier to create the table rather than calling the ranlib utility.

Answer (score 12):

A makefile is not a shell script.  It's a configuration file
for an expert system.  Specifically an expert system that
knows, if you tell it, how to efficiently create files and their
dependencies with a minimum of re-making files that don't need
to be remade.

If you look at the first rule you have:

```
myProgram: main.o addSorted.o freeLinks.o
    gcc -lm -o myProgram main.o addSorted.o freeLinks.o
```

that tells the system how to make a file called "myProgram" if it
decides that it needs to do that.  The parts after the colon
are files that myProgram needs.  If they aren't there, or
make decides they are out of date, make will try to find some
recipe that can be used to create or update them.  Once
all that is done, make then executes the "gcc ..." line and
assumes that will create or update myProgram.

The ar and ranlib lines you have don't match the needed syntax for
a makefile rule.  From the look of them, they appear to be
a recipe for making libmylib.a.  If you put them into the
syntax make needs to say that, you get:

```
libmylib.a: main.o addSorted.o freeLinks.o
    ar rcu libmylib.a main.o addSorted.o freeLinks.o
    ranlib libmylib.a
```

myProgram should depend on the library itself, rather than the
contents of the library, and it is best to put the library options at
the end:

```
myProgram: libmylib.a
    gcc -o myProgram libmylib.a -lm
```

if you like, you can use an option to tell gcc to look for libraries
in the current directory:

```
gcc -L. -o myProgram main.o -lmylib -lm
```

There are also makefile variables that can help you not have to repeat
so much, so I would write the first rule as:

```
myProgram: libmylib.a
    gcc -L. -o $@ -lmylib -lm
```

however, it is unlikely that main.o should actually be part of the library,
so:

```
myProgram: main.o libmylib.a
    gcc -L. -o $@ $< -lmylib -lm
```

and the library rule as:

```
libmylib.a: addSorted.o freeLinks.o
    ar rcu $@ $+
    ranlib $@
```

the $+ here means "all of the dependency file names".

Finally, if you want gcc to make an actual static executable, and not
just use the library you made, you need to pass the '-static' option
to gcc.

Comment: Can you also explain me for shared library?

Comment: Shared libraries are highly dependent on what system you are on.  On x86 or x86_64 linux, you need to compile the object files with -fpic, among other things.  Other systems may vary.