# How do I convert a normal Makefile to create a static executable that can be used on another computer

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, mosquitto

I got the `temp_conversion` example program from mosquitto C++, from [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto). I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421616/c-creating-static-library-and-linking-using-makefile) but I don't quite get it, I have minimal experience with makefiles. I'm not sure if static libraries even work this way, but I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to be able to move the executable to another pc and have it still run? (without installing mosquitto libraries there, maybe copying a static library created by the makefile with it)
2. How do I convert this makefile to make a static "moveable" executable?

The makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -ggdb -I../../lib -I../../lib/cpp
LDFLAGS=-L../../lib ../../lib/cpp/libmosquittopp.so.1 ../../lib/libmosquitto.so.1

.PHONY: all clean

all : mqtt_temperature_conversion

mqtt_temperature_conversion : main.o temperature_conversion.o
${CXX} $^ -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

main.o : main.cpp
    ${CXX} -c $^ -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

temperature_conversion.o : temperature_conversion.cpp
    ${CXX} -c $^ -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

clean : 
    -rm -f *.o mqtt_temperature_conversion
```

Comment: On which system are you ? Windows or Linux ?

Comment: linux -> lubuntu 14.04

Comment: You'll need to build mosquitto and all its dependencies into static library (it may or may not support this, also you may or may not violate licensing terms of this library and/or its dependencies) and link it, probably along with linking static C++ standard library. Also resulting executable will be portable only to some degree anyway.

Comment: C != C++. Tag with only one, unless both are used.

Comment: Why do you link the libraries like that and not link them with the `-l` option? ie `-lmosquitto`

Comment: @ChrisTurner This is the makefile delivered with the example, I am trying to get the example running like I described, using my limited experience with makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes you can compile on one computer and run it on another if they're running the same OS version. If you don't have the 3rd party libraries installed on the other computer, you will need to compile a static version of the program.

2) To compile a static version of a program you have to add the `-static` option to the final build command. This instructs the linker to use static versions of libraries if they exist, including the standard C++ library.

This won't work with what you have currently as it requires you to be adding libraries using the `-l` option. The `-l` option tells the linker to find a library in the library search path (specified by `-L`). Your Makefile is adding the libraries by filename, so it'll always use that specific version regardless of any other options you specify.

So to fix that you want something like this

```
LDFLAGS=-L../../lib -L../../lib/cpp -lmosquittopp -lmosquitto
```

...which adds the two directories where the libraries live to the search path and then says to link with both libraries. Then if you have static versions of those libraries, it'll use them when you add the `-static` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the static versions of your dependencies, here libmosquittopp. Find or install the static library, for example "libmosquittopp.a" (.a mean static library).
After that, link with your executable by replacing `libmosquittopp.so.1` and `libmosquitto.so.1` with the static version.

Comment: Building with the static libmosquitto may relieve the need to install Mosquitto on another machine, but it won't help with other dependencies that your application may have. If you're running the same Linux distribution and version on all machines, you'll probably get away with it. However, Linux users are generally more comfortable with installing dependencies than are users of most other popular platforms. It probably isn't fatal to the success of your application if users have to do "apt-get install mosquitto" or whatever.