# get "Makefile:1056: *** missing separator. Stop." while use make

Tags: makefile, imake

I create makefile with "xmkmf" command in imake using Ubuntu 14.04.3

when i run make command i get this error

```
Makefile:1056: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

line 1056 is:

```
MComplexProgramTarget(_cmidf_.o,$(LOCAL_LIBRARIES),)
```

Comment: This is duplicate of [Make error: missing separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator). Before posting your question on Stack Overflow you should attempt to search and see if anybody else has had a similar issue.

Comment: in line NO 1056 i don't have any space or tab or any extra character!

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears due to an unexpanded macro.  For instance, in a Debian 6 system, I see the `MComplexProgramTarget` macro used only in the `Motif.rules` file, which in turn is included from `cde.rules`, and *that* is not included by any of the platform-specific `imake` files.

Since it is unlikely that OP has Motif installed on Ubuntu, it seems more likely that this was cut/paste from some example which was originally written for Motif, e.g., for Solaris back in the 1990s (when CDE was supported).

Answer (score 3):

That line doesn't belong in a Makefile.

The file you're looking at is probably something like [this](http://www.opengroup.org/infosrv/openmotif/R2.1.30/motif/demos/programs/todo/Imakefile): no Makefile, but an Imakefile. You need to feed it to `xmkmf`, not to `make`.

If it is really in the `Makefile` generated by `xmkmf`, as you claim, something is wrong in the `IMakefile` that `xmkmf` generated it from.