# Makefile:1059: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, motif, imake

I have a project writed for DEC Unix v4. I want to compile it for linux.
My project have Imakefile, I run `xmkmf` to generate `Makefile` and after that run make to compile but I get `Makefile:1059: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

When I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32417160) I installed SparkyLinux and install CDE and `libmotif-dev` on it for Motif and CDE and again I am going to generate `Makefile` and run `make`, but my problem still

line 1059: `MComplexProgramTarget(_gdsv_.o,$(LOCAL_LIBRARIES),)`

Comment: instal BSD make (bmake, or pmake, it depends on the target platform)  The problem you have is that probably the xmkmf is generating berkeley makefile syntax. SEE MY ANSWER :)

Answer (score 1):

That line is valid in an `Imakefile`, but not in a `Makefile`. It looks like a macro for the C preprocessor. When the preprocessor does not find a definition for a macro, it leaves it as-is.

The next question is therefore: Why is the macro `MComplexProgramTarget` undefined, and which file defines it usually?

To answer this, you need to know where imake reads its definition files ("strace -f xmkmf" can help you with this), and in which file does this word appear?

Comment: when I run `xmkmf` show `imake -DUseInstalled -I/usr/lib/X11/config` in terminal. in your opinion this config can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The most probable thing is that you have lead to some incompatibility issue with `gmake`, which should be the make version you are using.  Install BSD make and use it to build the system.  Probably this will solve your problem (or not, but I have had this kind of problems)  Depending on the platform, the package is called `bmake` or `pmake`.

Comment: Can I convert imake file to pmake .mk file? An application exist for his propos?