# Why is my makefile still missing separator when I putted in I on my makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I don't understand why i got the error `makefile:10: *** missing separator.`
after I putted `I` on my makefile10 `I$(CXX) -o $@ $^  $(LDFLAGS)` . How can I fix my makefile so that it produce no error? Thanks

```
all: tetris

CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall

Board.o: Board.coo Board.h
Tetromino.o: Tetromino.cpp Tetromino.h
tetris.o: tetris.cpp Tetromino.h Board.h

tetris: tetris.o Tetromino.o Board.o
        I$(CXX) -o $@ $^  $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -f *.o teris
```

Comment: You are probably missing a **tab** at the start of the line.

Comment: The actual message I get is *Makefile:10: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.* And if I use tab, it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make error: missing separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)