# aodv.cc:1: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: ns2

I make some changes in "**aodv.cc**" in **NS-2.35**

now I want to use `make clean` to apply changes but this is what I give this error:

> aodv.cc:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

what should i do?

Comment: the most common cause for that error is that lines are indented with whitespaces when make expects tab characters.

Comment: thanks for your answer
it solved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make error: missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)