# Linux compliation Make error: missing separator

Tags: c, linux, makefile, pthreads

I'm trying to compile my program `thread.c` with the following Makefile:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
obj-m := thread.o
else

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
       $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif
```

When I run `make` I've got the error

> Makefile:10: *** missing separator.  Stop.

I'm not found the cause of this issue, someone can help me with this one ?

Comment: It usually has to do with the whitespace.  Try adding some before `obj-m := thread.o` and `$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make error: missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator)

Answer (score 2):

The commands in a rule's recipe must each start with a tab character.  More or other whitespace may follow, but the leading tab is essential.

Your file contains a rule for target `default`, but the single command in its recipe does not begin with a tab (or any whitespace, for that matter).  It turns out that that's line 10 (supposing that you have presented the whole file), which is indeed the line number implicated by `make`'s diagnostic.  Just insert the tab.  Personally, I would also add a blank line before the `endif`, but that's a style recommendation, not a requirement.  To wit:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

obj-m := thread.o

else

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

endif
```

Comment: Thank you! , I've added a "tab" on the first line and under the default and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've had this issue before, especially when using windriver. Typically I just nano the specific file its complaining about, delete the first space in the line then add it back. It's a weird fix but usually works for me.