# "Missing separator" but everything seems okay

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I can't run `make` with my Makefile. I got this message:

> Makefile:8: *** missing separator.  Stop.

I really don't know why, I already checked everything and I can't find any problem.

I already tried `cat -e -t -v Makefile` to see if I added a space, but I didn't find nothing.

Makefile code

```
CC=gcc
BINARY = airt
VERSION = v1.0.0-beta
FILES = chunk.h chunk.c memory.h memory.c common.h main.c

@echo $(VERSION)

@echo "Compiling..."
airt: $(FILES)
    $(CC) -o $(BINARY) $(FILES)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf $(BINARY)
```

Comment: for completeness can you confirm that "too see if I added a space" means you have ruled out the answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator

Comment: You can't have free-standing shell commands -- they must be inside a recipe.  See what message you get if you place a tab in front of the `@echo` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to use Make's [`info`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html) built-in function instead:

```
$(info $(VERSION))
```

---

Regarding the second `echo`, I would place it inside your target's recipe:

```
airt: $(FILES)
    @echo "Compiling..."
    $(CC) -o $(BINARY) $(FILES)
```

This way, the `echo` command will be executed by the shell, when the target `airt` is built.