# Makefile:77: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile, systemc

Hi I am trying to install systemC on WSL2, when I run `sudo make` I seem to be getting this error

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ryans/systemc-2.3.4/src'
Makefile:77: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ryans/systemc-2.3.4/src'
make: *** [Makefile:557: all-recursive] Error 1
```

I have looked at answers, [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920413/make-error-missing-separator) and [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop) but they don't seem to apply to my case because the file in question do not have a space or a tab at line 77.

[image]

Comment: Make doesn't have an `if` directive...

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the right way to install systemC on WSL is the run the following commands in the uncompressed `.tar` folder,

```
sudo aclocal
sudo automake --add-missing
sudo autoupdate
```

before making the `objdir` with the other instructions can be followed [here](https://howto.tech.blog/2016/11/27/installing-systemc-2-3-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Just cannot avoid answering this. You correctly quote other answers, so try this little exercise:

```
mkdir exercise
cd exercise
echo good > Makefile
make
```

As you'll probably see, the error will be exactly like yours. That is, a nearly-empty makefile can cause this error. Most of the time, as provided in the quoted answers, the error is tricky to find because there is a tab missing, or replaced by blanks. But in many other cases, the message appears where *something else* in the makefile is missing.

In the exercise above, `make` expects "good" to be a target, so it expects a ":" separator and complains about its absence.